# Temporarily storing report data onto AWS DynamoDB? Is this a viable solution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, reporting

I have a web application in which the users can run reports on data. The problem is that the queries are so slow because of the data we are working with.

I was thinking of making the process asynchronous and have another machine work on that thread: the querying of that data, putting it into AWS DynamoDB, and then notifying the users.

The data is flat for the most part (just rows and columns). Usually, the record size will range around in the 100s, sometimes 1000s, and rarely in the 10,000s.

Is this is a good idea? What would the performance be like?

Comment: What is the unit of record size? How do you plan to query it again and the nature of query from DynamoDB?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you further clarify what you're asking?

Comment: When you say you storing report data with record size of 100s, 1000s & etc.  what is 100? is it MB or KB or Rows or Columns etc?

Comment: Those are rows. The columns are.. I think up to 5, but not anymore than that.

Comment: Your question is lacking detail but if you're hoping to improve performance by using a cache, then use a cache (like Redis).

Comment: I'm sorry for being a little vague. I'm not trying to use a cache. I want to run a query, which takes a long time, and dump the data into DynamoDB, which the user would then pick up and display in the front end UI. Is that a viable and scalable solution? Does it make sense technically?

Comment: How is the original data stored ? In S3, or an SQL db ? One should play to strengths of each tool: SQL is good at performing queries that involve numerous columns and conditions, DynamoDb is more like a hash-lookup in a few specified fields . The SQL query time can be improved with eg subqueries that rapidly reduce the set of records that qualify - but I expect you know that !

Answer (score 1):

Classic architecture answer: "It depends"

1. If your long running query is on other Dynamo table(s) then storing the results in Dynamo makes some sense.  (familiar technology that you are already using).
2. If your query is running against some other database then why not store your results in a new table in that database, or a new dedicated database on the same platform?
3. Or keep it simple and just write your results to a file in S3 (json, xml, csv, whatever...)?

Comment: I was thinking that retrieving the data from DynamoDB would be faster than  retrieving it from the new database table and having to query that (in this case, we are using MS SQL Server). And... I didn't even think about approach number #3, what's the performance like on that?

Comment: Ideally the performance should be similar for all three solutions (assuming production class hardware and your result sets aren't huge).  But returning a static file will always be fastest...

Comment: @Scrappydog, how about if it requires querying with some conditions on the aggregated data? S3 CSV solution won't be able to support it, we need a database then.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @Scrappydog mentioned. You could do a mix of DynamoDB and S3.

1. DynamoDB would store the query meta data - like user id and S3 file names
2. S3 would store the actual query results in files

This would allow you to use DynamoDB to tie all the moving pieces together. Also would keep large writes out of DynamoDB to keep the cost down.